# To which concept does the term `partial` refer?

Tags: vimscript

From `:h Partial`:

```
A Funcref optionally binds a Dictionary and/or arguments.  This is also called
a Partial.  This is created by passing the Dictionary and/or arguments to
function() or funcref().  When calling the function the Dictionary and/or
arguments will be passed to the function.
```

To which concept does the term `Partial` refer?

I had some ideas, but I don't know which one, if any, is the right one:

- maybe it's called a `Partial`, because it's **partially** a function (the one to which the funcref refers), and **partially** data (the list of arguments or the dictionary, which are bound to the funcref)
- the data are **partially** linked to the function; maybe we could bind them to another function
- the list of arguments that the partial binds could be only a subset of the arguments used by the function to which the funcref refers; therefore, they're only a **part** of its arguments

Comment: Sounds like [Partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application).

Comment: @WouterDonders Thank you very much. I think you're right. The concept described in this link seems to be very similar to the `Partial` from Vim's help. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the help file is referring to the concept of partial application, which is [described in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) as:

> "[...] the process of fixing a number of arguments to a function, producing another function of smaller arity.